# TensorFlow: adding regularization to LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Following [Tensorflow LSTM Regularization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869744/tensorflow-lstm-regularization) I am trying to add regularization term to the cost function when training parameters of LSTM cells.

Putting aside some constants I have:

```
def RegularizationCost(trainable_variables):
    cost = 0
    for v in trainable_variables:
        cost += r(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(r(v.name),2)))
    return cost

...

regularization_cost = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = ())
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - y, 2)) + regularization_cost
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cost)

...

tv = tf.trainable_variables()
s = tf.Session()
r = s.run

...

while (...):
    ...

    reg_cost = RegularizationCost(tv)
    r(optimizer, feed_dict = {x: x_b, y: y_b, regularization_cost: reg_cost})
```

The problem I have is that adding the regularization term hugely slows the learning process and actually the regularization term `reg_cost` is increasing with each iteration visibly when the term associated with `pred - y` pretty much stagnated i.e. the `reg_cost` seems not to be taken into account.

As I suspect I am adding this term in completely wrong way. I did not know how to add this term in the cost function itself so I used a workaround with scalar tf.placeholder and "manually" calculated the regularization cost. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

compute the L2 loss only once:

```
tv = tf.trainable_variables()
regularization_cost = tf.reduce_sum([ tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tv ])
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - y, 2)) + regularization_cost
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cost)
```

you might want to remove the variables that are `bias` as those should not be regularized.

Answer (score 1):

It slows down because your code **creates new nodes in every iteration**. This is not how you code with TF. First, you create your whole graph, including regularization terms, then, in the while loop you only execute them, each "tf.XXX" operation creates **new nodes**.